# 301 redirect from index.html to /index/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a big problem to redirect a website. It is about 4100 pages large and I need a solution to redirect all pages automatically. The problem is that there are to many pages to do every page manually. For example...

I have a structure like this

```
car.com/audi.html
car.com/ford.html
...
```

And I need to redirect to

```
car.com/audi/
car.com/ford/
```

But my problem is the big number of pages. Is there a command or something that can redirect all pages in one? Or have I to redirect every single page?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CAR.COM</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=LINK_TO_DIRECTORY">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx but i'm looking for a redirect solution. But i will keep that in mind for my next project :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect .html requests to non-html (from old to new) you can use the following 1 liner redirect in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!index).+)\.html$ http://example.com/$1
```

Comment: looks awesome. Thanks! i will try out and give some feedback :)

Comment: Well it doesn't work.
the website redirects from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/index

this site doesn't exist... :-/

Comment: is it possible to do an exception for the root?

Comment: Yes, its possible. You just need to exclude the directory index file. try the updated code.